# Como é que eu poderia ter melhorado esta pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, voto-contra

Eu coloquei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146449/como-%C3%A9-que-posso-fazer-download-de-um-report-problema-de-cred%C3%AAnciais) já há algum tempo. Enquanto eu estou aberto a editar a minha pergunta para a melhorar não tenho a certeza o que falta nela. O votador não deixou nenhum comentário a explicar o que encontrou de errado.

Antes de ter colocado esta pergunta eu consultei pelo menos 4 perguntas semelhantes no SO EN e todos eles falavam para mudar as credênciais do cliente. Nenhuma das respostas menciounou que poderia haver um problema de acesso se o servidor de reports for diferente do servidor aplicacional.

Para complementar, eu também fiz essa pergutna sem intenção de responder por mim mesmo. Mas como consegui resolver o problema, respondi.

Como posso melhorar a minha pergunta?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que é o tipo de pergunta que só o autor pode responder, talvez até fosse até o caso de fechar como "não pode ser reproduzido". Não garanto porque pode ser que alguém que trabalhe com isso possa ver esse código e identificar esse problema, mas parece que pela descrição não tem como resolvê-la. Então a melhoria seria colocar informações do ambiente, porém se soubesse fazer isso no início acho que ela já estaria respondida.

Comment: @bigown Pois, esse é o problema. Mas enquanto eu posso concordar com o fecho com `não pode ser reproduzido`, não sei como eu na altura a poderia ter melhorado. Porque como menciou se pudesse teria o meu problema resolvido.

Comment: Por isso que talvez o fechamento fosse o adequado, não é uma pergunta que poderia ser respondida só lendo o que está escrito. E duvido que pudesse por alguma coisa nela que ajudasse responder, sem acabar tendo a resposta por conta própria. Ou seja, ela talvez não vá ajudar ninguém mais. Mas tenho minhas dúvidas, agora pode ser até que ajude.